# Create a separate QML file for MenuBar in a ApplicationWindow

Tags: qt, qml, qt-quick

I would create a separate file containing a component for a MenuBar in a ApplicationWindow. I have an original file like this:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MenuBar {
        Menu {
            title: qsTr("File")
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("&Open")
                onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
            }
            MenuItem {
                text: qsTr("Exit")
                onTriggered: Qt.quit();
            }
        }
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

But I would separate both to make a more complex menu in a separate file like this:

First File:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480
    title: qsTr("Hello World")

    menuBar: MyMenuBar{
    }

    Label {
        text: qsTr("Hello World")
        anchors.centerIn: parent
    }
}
```

Second File: (MyMenuBar.qml)

```
MenuBar {
    Menu {
        title: qsTr("File")
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("&Open")
            onTriggered: console.log("Open action triggered");
        }
        MenuItem {
            text: qsTr("Exit")
            onTriggered: Qt.quit();
        }
    }
}
```

I have tried with this solution but when I try to start the program it says `MyMenuBar is not a type`.

What's wrong?

Comment: Is your project using a `.qrc` file? If so, try running `qmake` again by right-clicking on the project in Creator and pressing `Run qmake`, then build your project again.

Comment: @Mitch is right. Your resource file `.qrc` should look like [this](https://gist.github.com/ftena/ef94e24d2e0727a26917).

Answer (score 1):

There is nothing wrong with your `qml` files. If you put both the files within the same directory and run `qmlscene main.qml` (considering that `main.qml` is your first file) you will get the desired result. If you are using c++ code in your project, you might want to add all the `qml` files in `qrc` file as suggested in the comments. If you don't have such desires, I think there is something wrong with your project file. I would suggest you to create a new `Qt Quick UI` project and put your first file code in the file created and then right click on the project and click `add new` and select `Qt > QML file` and name it `MyMenuBar.qml` and put your code in it. I think this should solve your problem.